# How do a start python in a virtual environment with the packages installed to the venv in the correct path?

Tags: python, python-venv

After activating a python virtual environment at the terminal with `source ./venv/bin/activate`, and running python3 in the venv, it doesn't seem to have the packages from the venv in the path.

```
(venv) d@MBP-2020 scrapers % ls venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages | grep "pandas"
pandas
pandas-1.5.2.dist-info

(venv) d@MBP-2020 scrapers % pip list | grep "pandas"
pandas           1.5.2

(venv) d@MBP-2020 scrapers % python3
Python 3.11.0 (v3.11.0:deaf509e8f, Oct 24 2022, 14:43:23) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

>>> import sys; print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
```

I thought activating the venv would put the venv-installed packages in the right path for the python3 executable? Must I manually add the site-packages directory to the path somehow?

What is the right workflow to access packages installed venvs with python?

Comment: it has take base packages from default python location, newly added package will be the site package of venv

Comment: use pyenv if you want whole control on. venv

Comment: I don't want to use a bigger solution like pyenv if I don't have to. The answer was simpler-- just run the python in ./venv/bin/python3.11 and everything works with the imported packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this pip is not match you cmd `python3` run python env,
you can use `whereis pip` and `whereis python3` to check you pip and python3 real link to where.

1. if your want to use venv py.
   run `venv/lib/python3.11/bin/python`, this env is your grep cmd search dir,and is installed pandas lib py env,

you can usr `pyenv` or `conda` to manage you mulit version.

Comment: For me the path to the python I needed to use so that the packages were in the path was ./venv/bin/python3.11. Using that fixed my problem. Thanks!